# C# Com Enum and VB6

Tags: c#, com, vb6, enums, com-interop

Hi I created C# Exe Com Server and refer it from VB6 application.
The problem is that all the enums are exposed with "strange name" in the vb app: EnumName_EnumeItem, while reffered from then VB6 code as EnumName.EnumItem.

The VB6 application code cannot be modified.
Wondering around I saw I can change this definitions by changing the idl extract fro the tlb, but failed to understand exactly how it's done, and what are the tools for the job.

Any suggestions how to set the enums easily as possible?

The code:

```
 public enum enResultCode : uint
{
    enRCNone = 0x00000000,
    enRCNotFound = 0x00000001,
    enRCFoundOnServer = 0x00000002,
    enRCFoundOnLocal = 0x00000003,
    enRCDatabaseError = 0x00000004,
    enRCAborted = 0xFFFFFFFF,
    enRCServerError = 0xFFFFFFFE,
    enRCLocalError = 0xFFFFFFFD
}
```

Shown in VB6 as:

[image]

instead of:

```
enResultCode.EnumItemName
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're correct the only way to do this is to modify the IDL yourself.  I can tell you a little about how it's done...

1. You run tlbexp.exe to create the tlb from your C# assembly.
2. You run oleview.exe to open that tlb and inspect the IDL.  You can save that IDL out to a file or copy/paste it.
3. You edit the IDL to give it the enum item names you want.
4. You run midl.exe to generate a tlb from your modified IDL.

That should be enough.  Sorry I can't give you all the correct command line switches but I'm not on a Windows machine right now.

Comment: This is backed up by [this article](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2010/05/17/interop-remove-prefix-from-c-enums-for-com.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I have some issues creating the tlb from idl. Will comment about it later (after I'll have the answers).